# Не деплоится артефакт

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, maven

Есть много-модульный проект, решил его view делать в веб интерфейсе поэтому подключаю модуль crawler-core в maven как war проект, но при деплое артефакта получаю следующий лог, причем исключения не вылетают

```
2016-08-20 10:53:12 INFO  ContextLoader:285 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2016-08-20 10:53:12 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:513 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Aug 20 10:53:12 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-20 10:53:12 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [appConfig-mvc.xml]
2016-08-20 10:53:15 INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-08-20 10:53:15 INFO  Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.9.Final}
2016-08-20 10:53:15 INFO  Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-20 10:53:15 INFO  Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-20 10:53:15 INFO  Configuration:2075 - HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
2016-08-20 10:53:15 INFO  Configuration:2094 - HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
2016-08-20 10:53:15 INFO  Configuration:2216 - HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
2016-08-20 10:53:16 INFO  ConnectionProviderInitiator:190 - HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
2016-08-20 10:53:16 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:134 - HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: org.postgresql.Driver at URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/web-crawler-shops
2016-08-20 10:53:16 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:135 - HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
2016-08-20 10:53:16 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:138 - HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
2016-08-20 10:53:17 INFO  Dialect:145 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2016-08-20 10:53:17 INFO  LobCreatorBuilder:123 - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-08-20 10:53:18 INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator:62 - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2016-08-20 10:53:18 INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-20 10:53:19 INFO  SchemaExport:344 - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-08-20 10:53:19 INFO  SchemaExport:406 - HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-08-20 10:53:19 INFO  Configuration:2111 - HHH000044: Configuring from URL: file:/C:/Users/Пользователь/IdeaProjects/web-crawler-shops/crawler-core/target/web-crawler-shops/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml
2016-08-20 10:53:19 INFO  Configuration:2216 - HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
2016-08-20 10:53:19 INFO  ConnectionProviderInitiator:190 - HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
2016-08-20 10:53:19 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:134 - HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: org.postgresql.Driver at URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/web-crawler-shops
2016-08-20 10:53:19 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:135 - HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
2016-08-20 10:53:19 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:138 - HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
2016-08-20 10:53:20 INFO  Dialect:145 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2016-08-20 10:53:20 INFO  LobCreatorBuilder:123 - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-08-20 10:53:20 INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator:62 - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2016-08-20 10:53:20 INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-20 10:53:20 INFO  SchemaExport:344 - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-08-20 10:53:20 INFO  SchemaExport:406 - HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-08-20 10:53:20 INFO  HibernateTransactionManager:339 - Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@d052136f [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@f8c64892 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hgeby99i1abigr6jorhq6|6adf7783, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 1000, initialPoolSize -> 7, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 100, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 53, maxStatements -> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 7, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@b062043a [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hgeby99i1abigr6jorhq6|70f1eeea, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/web-crawler-shops, properties -> {user=******, password=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hgeby99i1abigr6jorhq6|900f5d1, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2016-08-20 10:53:20 INFO  ContextLoader:325 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8068 ms
20-Aug-2016 10:53:20.467 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
20-Aug-2016 10:53:20.467 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/crawler] startup failed due to previous errors
2016-08-20 10:53:20 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:873 - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Aug 20 10:53:12 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
20-Aug-2016 10:53:20.576 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [crawler] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2016-08-20 10:53:20,638] Artifact crawler-core:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Раньше такого не было, зависимости вроде все на месте

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>crawler-core</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>ua.nike185.crawler</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-crawler-shops</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ua.nike185.crawler</groupId>
        <artifactId>crawler-modules-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ua.nike185.crawler</groupId>
        <artifactId>olx-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>web-crawler-shops</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Вот структура проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Spring mvc config [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше создавал java web проекты было все ок, а здесь второй день уже бьюсь. В чем  может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ребята я нашел решение.
Вообщем я web xml брал из своего предыдущего проекта(был сконфигурирован как мне надо) но предыдущий проект использовал spring security, а этот нет. И там в web xml был добавлен фильтр от spring security который и не давал мне задеплоить артефакт, так как этот проект не использовал spring security!! Вообщем будьте внимательны, потратил 3 дня на это дело (